# How can I access specific items from multiple lists when the user input is based on what needs to be iterated from the lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have been working on this homework problem for a week now and I can't wrap my brain around something that seems so simple. I have 4 lists and trying to iterate specific items from each list in a for loop based on what the user Input is. The problem is when I try to access specific items from the list, it results in multiples of what I want in the output. I am supposed to be utilizing a collection in the Homework problem. I am not looking for anyone to do this problem for me but rather help me with what I'm doing wrong. Is my issue how I set up my lists or my for-loop? Should I be using tuples instead...?

```
# List items are ordered. so all of possition [0] is information for course1. 
#   Position [1] is for course2 and so on. 
courseID  = ['course1','course2','course3','course4'] #Provided Info
room      = ['room1', 'room2', 'room3', 'room4']     #Provided Info
proffessor = ['teacher1', 'teacher2', 'teacher3', 'teacher4'] #Provided Info
text       = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4'] #Provided Info

userInput = input('Enter Course Number: ') #Get User Input 
for i in courseID: #For loop to cycle through the info provided
    if userInput == courseID[0]:
        print('room: ',room[0])
        print('professor: ',[proffessor[0]])
        print('Text: ', text[0])
    else:
        if userInput == courseID[1]:
            print('room: ',room[1])
            print('professor: ',[proffessor[1]])
            print('Text: ', text[1])
        else:
            if userInput == courseID[2]:
                print('room: ',room[2])
                print('professor: ',[proffessor[2]])
                print('Text: ', text[2])

OUTPUT=
Enter Course Number: course1
room:  room1
professor:  ['teacher1']
Text:  text1
room:  room1
professor:  ['teacher1']
Text:  text1
room:  room1
professor:  ['teacher1']
Text:  text1
room:  room1
professor:  ['teacher1']
Text:  text1
```

Output im looking for:

```
Enter Course Number: Course #
room: room #
professor: teacher
text: text
```

Comment: It's hard to understand the problem, because there is no such thing as "calling" an item from a list. "call" means what you do with functions to make the code inside them run.

Comment: as you can tell im not a seasoned programmer. I only just started learning, so my terminology understanding is a work in progress. I appreciate your help though..

Comment: You only want to find one course, you don't need the three if-else clauses, they only hard-code each possible value of index 0,1,2. You can avoid needing the `for i in courseID: ... if userInput == courseID[0]:` by just using `courseID.index(userInput)` method, which returns the corresponding index, or raises ValueError, which you can suppress with `try... except ValueError`.

Comment: (By the way, Python allows `if... elif`. You don't need to write `if... else: if...`, and you don't need that ragged indenting. But as above, the three hardcoded if-else clauses are unnecessary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More simply you could get the index of the input value in courseID and then use that index to access each of the other Lists. This eliminates your if-else chain.

```
courseID=['course1','course2','course3','course4'] #Provided Info
room = ['room1', 'room2', 'room3', 'room4']     #Provided Info
proffessor = ['teacher1', 'teacher2', 'teacher3', 'teacher4'] #Provided Info
text= ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4'] #Provided Info

userInput= input('Enter Course Number: ') #Get User Input

if userInput in courseID:
    idx = courseID.index(userInput)
    print('room ', room[idx])
    print('professor ', proffessor[idx])
    print('text ', text[idx])
    
else:
    print('unknown course')
```

Comment: This definitely works. Thank you for the answer. I am glad someone understood what i was trying to say as im very new to programming.

Comment: You made a good attempt. Keep going! One hint - when you see repeated code (such as within your if-else chain) then think about replacing it with less code. Do not repeat yourself is a basic mantra.